# ISPC - can I limit the number of CPU threads to 1?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, ispc

I'm using a ISPC-based program on Windows and I'm wondering if there's any way to limit the number of CPU threads to 1 since I have to run some experiments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `SetProcessAffinityMask` [(msdn link)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686223%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function:

```
BOOL SetProcessAffinityMask(
  HANDLE hProcess,
  DWORD_PTR dwProcessAffinityMask
);
```